# Как выйти из man при этом не останавливая сам процесс?

Tags: bash, cmd, unix, консоль, terminal

Пытаюсь разобраться, как можно переключится на другой процесс, при этом не прерывая текущий. 
И как потом к текущему вернуться. 
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`screen` вам в помощь. Запускаем `screen`, в открывшейся сессии запускаем нужный процесс. Жмем ctrl+a, d для отключения от сессии где запущен процесс. Для переключения обратно к сессии screen набираем `screen -r <номер сессии screen>` попадаем туда где оставили запущенный процесс.
Если сессия больше не нужна, то находясь в сессии жмем ctrl+a, k и положительно отвечаем на предложение кильнуть сессию.

> Этим способом, так-же удобно пользоваться при нестабильном ssh подкючении.

Answer (score 7):

**jobs**, **fg**, **bg** – управление фоновыми процессами

Что бы запустить задачу в фоновом режиме надо в конце команды добавить знак **&**, либо запустить её в обычном режиме, после чего нажать комбинацию **ctrl+Z**, отправив ей сигнал TSTR. Что бы продолжить её выполнение в фоновом режиме используется команда bg (background).

Отобразить список текущих фоновых задач можно командой jobs.

Что бы вывести задачу из фонового режима – используется команда fg (foreground), которой можно либо передать номер задачи в качестве аргумента.

Например:

```
$ tar cpf somefile.tar somefolder 2>/dev/null                               #  запускаем tar 
^Z                                                                          # нажимаем Ctrl+Z
[1]+  Stopped                 tar cpf somefile.tar somefolder 2>/dev/null
$ jobs                                                                      # Смотрим список задач
[1]+  Stopped                 tar cpf somefile.tar somefolder 2>/dev/null
$ bg 1                                                                      # Продолжаем выполнение первой задачи в фоне
[1]+ tar cpf somefile.tar somefolder 2>/dev/null
$ fg 1                                                                      # Выводим задачу на передний план
```

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, действительно удобно. Но у этого способа есть один недостаток, если действовать таким способом, то процесс уводимый в bg реально ставится на паузу (о чем и свидетельствует сообщение "Stopped") и возобновляет работу, только при переключении в fg. Для man более чем идеальный вариант, но вот если этот процесс должен что-то выполнять в фоне, тогда не получается.

Comment: После Ctrl+Z возобновить работу процесса можно командой fg на переднем плане либо командой bg за заднем плане. После выполнения команды bg увидите сообщение "Runing", а не "Stopped" .

Comment: Да, точно, но если при этом процесс должен что-то выводить в stdout то выглядит это весьма любопытно )))